# Why does my program straight out skip the very first instruction past the initialization of my variables?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to write a program that calculates an expression from left to right (so like the operations are executed in the order they are input). For example:

```
Enter an expression: 1+2.5*3
Value of expression: 10.5
```

So, I'm supposed to do this without using arrays or string. My idea was to keep scanning for chars until the char scanned was different from any number from 0 to 9. Then, the chars get converted to floats and according to what the last char scanned was, the operations of sum, multiplication and whatnot get executed.

Here's what I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  char digit = ' ';
  int counter = 0;
  int number = 0
  float reversed_number = 0, reversed_decimal = 0, reversed_number2 = 0,
        reversed_decimal2 = 0, result = 0;

  printf("Enter an expression: ");

  while(digit != '\n') {
  for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
    digit = getchar();
    number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
  }
  for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
    reversed_number = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
    number /= 10;
  }

  if(digit == '.'){
    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
      digit = getchar();
      number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
      reversed_decimal = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
      number /= 10;
      counter++;
    }
    reversed_decimal /= pow(10, counter - 1);
    reversed_number += reversed_decimal;
    counter = 0;
  }

  else if(digit == '+'){
    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
      digit = getchar();
      number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
      reversed_number2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
      number /= 10;
    }
    if(digit == '.'){
      for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
        digit = getchar();
        number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
      }
      for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
        reversed_decimal2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
        number /= 10;
        counter++;
      }
      reversed_decimal2 /= pow(10, counter - 1);
      reversed_number2 += reversed_decimal2;
      counter = 0;
    }
    result += reversed_number + reversed_number2;
  }

  else if(digit == '-'){
    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
      digit = getchar();
      number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
      reversed_number2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
      number /= 10;
    }
    if(digit == '.'){
      for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
        digit = getchar();
        number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
      }
      for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
        reversed_decimal2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
        number /= 10;
        counter++;
      }
      reversed_decimal2 /= pow(10, counter - 1);
      reversed_number2 += reversed_decimal2;
      counter = 0;
    }
    result += reversed_number - reversed_number2;
  }

  else if(digit == '*'){
    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
      digit = getchar();
      number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
      reversed_number2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
      number /= 10;
    }
    if(digit == '.'){
      for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
        digit = getchar();
        number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
      }
      for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
        reversed_decimal2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
        number /= 10;
        counter++;
      }
      reversed_decimal2 /= pow(10, counter - 1);
      reversed_number2 += reversed_decimal2;
      counter = 0;
    }
    result += reversed_number * reversed_number2;
  }

  else if(digit == '/'){
    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
      digit = getchar();
      number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
      reversed_number2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
      number /= 10;
    }
    if(digit == '.'){
      for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
        digit = getchar();
        number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
      }
      for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
        reversed_decimal2 = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
        number /= 10;
        counter++;
      }
      reversed_decimal2 /= pow(10, counter - 1);
      reversed_number2 += reversed_decimal2;
      counter = 0;
    }
    result += reversed_number / reversed_number2;
  }
  }

  printf("Value of expression: %g", result);

  return 0;
}
```

The code gets compiled just fine with no warnings whatsoever, but when I run the program, something weird happens and it doesn't even print out "Enter an expression: " and it just keeps on listening for user inputs. I don't really understand why... even if the code was completely wrong altogether with my reasoning, it should at the very least print out the very first printf function, as nothing before it could make the program loop.

What exactly is going on here? Because I have no idea

Comment: Does a space meet this criteria? `digit >= 48 && digit <= 57` In fact all of your for loop clauses seem suspect to me.

Comment: "So, I'm supposed to do this without using arrays or string. My idea was to keep scanning for chars until the char scanned was different from any number from 0 to 9. Then, the chars" i am really curious about how you'll do that. Especially the "then, the chars"-part.

Comment: well no, you're right actually. But shouldn't it print Enter an expression anyways? @RetiredNinja

Comment: You might want to add `fflush(stdout);` after the input prompt, and `printf("Value of expression: %g", result);` --> `printf("Value of expression: %g\n", result);`.

Comment: @Swordfish so basically I scan for a char one at a time till it's different to what I said above. So then I know that the ASCII value of 0 is 48, of 1 is 49 and so on, so if char a = '0', int number = a - 48. Knowing that, I can just do a for loop where I add to the number ten to power of i (I is a variable that starts from 0 and gets augmented by 1 at each cycle) times (a - 48). So now if the user inputed 125, the number would be equal to 521. All I need to do now is reverse it.

Comment: `while(digit != '\n) {` without any warnings eh?

Comment: @Swordfish for the reversing part I use a second for loop with a variable i that goes from 0 and augments by 1 at each cycle, and I say that the reversed number (actual number that the user has inputted) is equal to 10 to the power of i times the unreversed number divided by ten. Also at each cycle I divide the number by 10.

Comment: @FoxyIT Sorry, but thats just ... hm ... awkward. try to read a double if it fails you know you have to read chars until you encounter an operator. start over.

Comment: @n.m. I typed that while directly in here, it was just a typo.

Comment: thats why you should copy&paste. But it makes one wonder: why do you have to type something manually when you claim to have tested that code?

Comment: @Swordfish I forgot to add the while instruction in the original code and realized it while I was posting it, so I just added it directly here for completition sake. The program runs both with and without that while function ahah

Comment: getchar() doesn't do what you think it does.  The C library uses input the way it worked back in the 1970s, teletypes machines were used back then.  Nothing happens until you press the Enter key.  Getting instant input from typing a single key requires a non-standard function whose name depends on the OS you use.

Answer (score 2):

> something weird happens and it doesn't even print out "Enter an expression: "

This is because of I/O buffering. `printf` does not immediately write, it uses a buffer. For `stdout` this is a line buffer meaning it will only flush the buffer (ie. write) when it sees a newline. Since you never print a newline `stdout` is never flushed. You can explicitly flush `stdout`.

```
printf("Enter an expression: ");
fflush(stdout);
```

> and it just keeps on listening for user inputs

A few debugging prints reveals the problem.

```
while(digit != '\n') {
    printf("Top of while digit: '%c'\n", digit);

    for(int i = 0; digit >= 48 && digit <= 57; i++){
        puts("in loop");
        digit = getchar();
        printf("  digit: '%c'\n", digit);
        number += pow(10, i)*(digit - 48);
    }
    printf("After first loop: '%c'\n", digit);
    for(int i = 0; number == 0; i++){
        printf("In second loop, number: %d\n", number);
        reversed_number = pow(10, i)*(number / 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    printf("Digit: '%c'\n", digit);
```

```
$ ./test
Enter an expression: Top of while digit: ' '
After first loop: ' '
In second loop, number: 0
In second loop, number: 0
In second loop, number: 0
In second loop, number: 0
In second loop, number: 0
...
```

The first loop sees `digit` is  and immediately exits without ever calling `getchar`. This leaves `number == 0` so the second loop endlessly runs `number /= 10` which is 0.

Instead if you want to process line by line, read a line, then parse it.

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
for( int i = 0; line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
    printf("%c", line[i]);
}
```

Then to further clean up your code, you can use [`isdigit` and friends](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C_character_classification#/Overview_of_functions) instead of checking individual ASCII codes.

```
    if( isdigit(*c) ) {
        printf("%c is a digit!\n", *c);
    }
```

Alternatively, this is an appropriate time to use [`scanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) to read and parse entire numbers from input.

Comment: I don't understand the second part. Let's say that the user inputs `21\n`. first cycle goes through with i = 0, digit is equal to 2, so second cycle goes through with i = 1 and now digit is equal to 1. Third cycle then goes through, `\n` gets assigned to digit so the cycle should be over, as `48 <= digit && digit <= 57` is no longer verified, right?

Comment: @FoxyIT I've shown just enough to illustrate how to read a line character by character, and a better way to identify digits. What you do with those digits is up to you. But you're probably better off using `scanf` as it can already parse numbers.

Comment: I mean I get that what you wrote is better and everything, but this exercise is 2 chapters before pointer and 1 chapter before arrays, so I should solve it without using them. Also yeah, using the scanf was a much better option to begin with and I'll rewrite the whole program using that but I'm still wondering why my for loop doesn't work as I said

Comment: @FoxyIT I've edited the question to not use pointers. And I realized my explanation why it's hanging was wrong, I fixed that. Good luck with your homework, making a calculator is a bit advanced if you haven't even gotten to arrays and pointers.